# Error 1442 (HY000): Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by a statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Hope everyone is well.

I am trying to move data from one table to another but I'm getting the below error, it is literally driving me insane as I can't see any logical reason why it won't work - infact I've ran the same query in the past no problem at all!

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'bb_events' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

The query I am running is:

```
INSERT INTO `bb_events` (
    `account_id`, 
    `device_id`, 
    `timestamp`, 
    `status_code`, 
    `latitude`, 
    `longitude`, 
    `speed`, 
    `heading`, 
    `odometer`, 
    `address`, 
    `street`, 
    `city`, 
    `state`, 
    `postcode`, 
    `country`, 
    `geozone_id`, 
    `battery_volts`, 
    `driver_id`, 
    `engine_time`, 
    `idle_time`, 
    `work_time`) 
SELECT 
    `accountID` AS `account_id`, 
    `deviceID` AS `device_id`, 
    `timestamp` AS `timestamp`,
    `statusCode` AS `status_code`, 
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`,
    `speedKPH`*0.621371192 AS `speed`,
    `heading`,
    `odometerKM`*0.621371192 AS `odometer`, 
    `address`,
    `streetAddress` AS `street`,
    `city`, 
    `stateProvince` AS `state`,
    `postalCode` AS `postcode`, 
    `country`,
    `geozoneID` AS `geozone_id`,
    `batteryVolts` AS `battery_volts`,
    `driverID` AS `driver_id`,
    `engineHours`*3600 AS `engine_time`,
    `idleHours`*3600 AS `idle_time`,
    `workHours`*3600 AS `work_time` 
FROM 
    `EventData`;
```

On the `bb_events` table I have a trigger setup which is as follows:-

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `event_insert_after` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `event_insert_after` AFTER INSERT ON `bb_events`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE `bb_device` SET `latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `status_code` = NEW.`status_code`, `timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `speed` = NEW.`speed`, `driver_id` = NEW.`driver_id`, `heading` = NEW.`heading` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62465 THEN 
        INSERT INTO `bb_journey` (`account_id`, `device_id`, `start_timestamp`, `start_street`, `start_city`, `start_state`, `start_country`, `start_latitude`, `start_longitude`, `start_geozone`, `start_odometer`) VALUES (NEW.`account_id`, NEW.`device_id`, NEW.`timestamp`, NEW.`street`, NEW.`city`, NEW.`state`, NEW.`country`, NEW.`latitude`, NEW.`longitude`, NEW.`geozone_id`, NEW.`odometer`);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = (SELECT `id` FROM `bb_journey` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)  WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF; 
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62467 THEN 
        UPDATE `bb_journey` SET `end_timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `end_street` = NEW.`street`, `end_city` = NEW.`city`, `end_state` = NEW.`state`, `end_country` = NEW.`country`, `end_latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `end_longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `end_geozone` = NEW.`geozone_id`, `end_odometer` = NEW.`odometer` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `current_journey` FROM `bb_device` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = '' WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

I have tried running this trigger before insert, this didn't work either. Surely this has got to be a simple fix :S.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: I could be wrong here but I think the problem is that your trigger is being dropped when it is being ran!

Can you confirm if the code you have shown is the actual code being ran or just the setup code you used to create the trigger in the first place?

Comment: It was the code used for setup, however i changed it to run before, then back to run after. I did this with Navicat purely for ease, although I can try dropping the trigger and re-creating it?

Comment: Your trigger posted does not seem to be cause of the error. But I fear it was due to any of `insert` and `update` statements used in the body. Check if the tables `bb_journey` and `bb_device` have any triggers defined on them. If yes, check if they are calling any DML's on table `bb_events`.

Comment: Bingo, I had something in a trigger on the "bb_journey" table that runs on update. What it did was set the `journey_id` field on all records in the "bb_events" table that were between the start/end timestamp, this could be 10 rows or 1000.. I took this out and it instantly worked, i will have to re-think the logic for this :).